# soup.find("div", id = "tournamentTable"), None returned - python 2.7 - BS 4.5.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm Trying to parse the following page: http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/

The part I'm interested in is getting the table along with the scores and odds.

The code I have so far:

```
url = "http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/france/ligue-1-2015-2016/results/"
req = requests.get(url, timeout = 9)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
print soup.find("div", id = "tournamentTable"), soup.find("#tournamentTable")

>>> <div id="tournamentTable"></div> None
```

Very simple but I'm thus weirdly stuck at finding the table in the tree. Although I found already prepared datasets I would like to know to why the printed strings are a tag and None.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this page uses JavaScript to fetch data, if you disable the JS in your browser, you will notice that the div tag exist but nothing in it, so, the first will print a single tag.
[image]

Second, `#` is CSS selector, you can not use it in `find()`

> Any argument that’s not recognized will be turned into a filter on one
>   of a tag’s attributes.

so, the second `find` will to find some tag with `#tournamentTable` as it's attribute, and nothing will be match, so it will return `None`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the table gets populated with an Ajax call back to the server. That is why why you print `soup.find("div", id = "tournamentTable")` you get only the empty tag. When you print `soup.find("#tournamentTable")`, you get None because that is trying to find a element with the *tag* "#tournamentTable". If you want to use CSS selectors, you should use [`soup.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) like this, `soup.select('#tournamentTable')` or `soup.select('div#tournamentTable')` if you want to be even more particular.